# error propagation for derivatives

Tags: standard-deviation, dataset, uncertainty, error-propagation, derivative

I have the following problem:

I have some data of a function *f(x)* with a set of 300 values of it associated to the same number of values of *x* including corresponding standard deviation *σ(f)* for each point.

I read how to propagate uncertainties for composed functions *g(f)*, that is, the procedure that allow you to find σ(g).

However, I don't know calculate *σ(g)* when *g = f'*.

How can I propagate uncertainties of f to its derivative?

I hope someone could help me with this question

Thanks a lot.